# how to delete a specific line in file c++

Tags: c++

my professor told us to create a program that will be able to add , list and delete a employee record and my problem here is that i dont know how i can delete a record from the file . the code that i'm using is its only copying the content of the original file and not the new content.

Here's my code:

```
string del;
string line;
ifstream in("sample.txt");
if (!in.is_open()) {
    cout << "Input file failed to open\n";
        }
ofstream out("temp.txt")`enter code here`;
cout << "Please Enter the Employee No. to delete" << endl;
cin >> del;
while (getline(in, line)) {
    if (line != del)
        out << line << endl;
}
in.close();
out.close();
remove("sample.txt");
rename("temp.txt", "sample.txt");
```

Comment: Read the records from file into your data structure, do your add/list/delete on the data structure, then write the data structure to the file. For the record you probably want to make a `struct Record` with all the fields and overloads to read from and write to a stream and then use `std::vector<Record> records;` as the data structure.

Comment: Check the contents of `del` and `line`. They're probably differing slightly.

Comment: @UKMonkey: A SO question's validity is not predicated on the presence of a `?` character.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're right - I didn't read it in full ... I just scanned to the end  ... sorry OP :)

Answer (score 0):

> i dont know how i can delete a record from the file . the code that i'm using is its only copying the content of the original file and not the new content.

You can't delete a specific line from the textfile. You can only rewrite the same content till the line you want to delete  to another file, skip the line(s) to be deleted, continue writing the rest of the contents.

Once done, delete the original file and rename the new file as the original.

Your code is doing the same thing and it is alright.

Another alternative will be storing the current file content in a data structure such as Vector. Make your changes such as deletion/adding in the data structure.

Then write the content of the data structure back into the file.

Comment: Okay so now your answer does little other than re-iterate what the OP's code is doing, then deny that there is a question. Not useful.

Answer (score -1):

One of the common ways to 'delete' things in files is to not actually delete them at all, but to either set a flag to say they're deleted or to blank them out another way.  For example one could have a format

```
<valid>:<number>:<name> 
eg 1:123:Dave
```

This can then be deleted by setting the leading 1 to a 0.

You can then rewrite the file and remove all the deleted ones at a later time.
An alternative would be to just fill the line with spaces and allow your program to skip blank lines.

Comment: I think someone just mass down voted everyone's answer.

Comment: @user3437460 so it would seem... and with no reason or explanation at all to it.  Still; what I said is a simplified version of what's used by databases ... and some of the other answers are helpful (I've not read them all in detail); so I'm sure positive votes will float around soon

Answer (score -2):

You have need to read file and store in data structure then perform delete operation and send data to original file.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
    infile>>vectorObject[i];           
 }
 cin>>del;
 remove(vectorObject[del-1]);
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 { 
    outfile<<vectorObject[i];
  }
```

According to your question this will work.

Comment: Why is it necessary to buffer the entire file contents? That is very inefficient and I don't see how it will solve the problem.